# Bootstrap 4.1.1 Navbar not working with Angular 6

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I have been trying to work on Navbar with collapse menu and dropdown link using Bootstrap 4.1.1 and Angular 6 but somehow Navbar is not working at all. I can see elements correctly but they don't function as intended.

I installed Bootstrap via Angular CLI using 'ng install bootstrap --save' and Bootstrap dependencies: 'ng install jquery --save' and 'ng install popper.js --save'

I also included Bootstrap, jquery and popper.js in package.json and angular.json

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
  "core-js": "^2.5.4",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
  "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
  "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/jquery": "^3.3.2",
  "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
  "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~1.7.1",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.3.0",
  "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
  "tslint": "~5.9.1",
  "typescript": "~2.7.2"
}
```

angular.json:

```
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">RecipeBook</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsing-nav-bar" aria-controls="collapsing-nav-bar"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsing-nav-bar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Recipes</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Shopping list</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Manage
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Save</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Fetch</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I prefer using Bootstrap native library and I rather not use ng-bootstrap nor hacks like including CDNs in head-tag.

Am I doing something wrong here ? Any advice on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: to include bootstrap, you should include/import the bootstrap css file in your styles.css file, not the `styles` array property in your angular.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add **umd** directries popper in script.

```
 "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your advice I was able to some extent repair it. Just changing popper.js url I got Navbar's dropdown working. I didn't think distribution folder could affect outcome so much. Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue but my `popper.min.js` is correct. It is under `umd`. I noticed though that it works when app is build and run in a server (`http-server`) but not if during dev mode  (`ng serve`).

Answer (score 3):

I have lost 2 hours chasing ghosts. Notice that there is two scripts segment in angular.json. One under **test** and one under **build**. You should add under build segment. I was adding under test so angular didn't see bootstrap, and popper js

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myBootstrapTestApp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"]
          },
```

Comment: Amazing! This had me knocking my head against a wall. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

path to popper should be : **node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/**

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

After some time i have only put the bootstrap library below the jquery and the popper order...

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/fontawesome/index.js"
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "core-js": "^2.5.4",
   "jquery": "^3.3.1",
   "popper.js": "^1.14.3",

}
"devDependencies": {    
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.2",
}
```

Also this to angular.json

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

            ]
          },
```

be sure to run npm install after making these changes.