# Bootstrap Hamburger not opening

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have followed step by step procedure for the implementation of Hamburger in navbar. However on resizing windows the navbar is collapsing but it is not opening on clicking it.

Please refer to the below sample code for reference. I'm using bootstrap4 & angular 6 version.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
<nav class="navbarc navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 rounded navbar-fixed-top" style="padding: 0.5rem !important;
margin-bottom: .5rem !important; border-radius: 4px;
 padding: 05px;">

    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-links" style="font-size: 16px;" routerLink="">Special Discount <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-links" style="font-size: 16px;" routerLink="Products">Products on Discount</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
angular.json
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "myapp": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "app",
            "schematics": {},
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/myapp",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
                            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                        ],
                        "es5BrowserSupport": true
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [{
                                "type": "initial",
                                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                "maximumError": "5mb"
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                },

package.json -
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/cli": "^6.1.3",
        "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/material": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
        "angular-user-idle": "^2.1.4",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "forms": "^1.3.1",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "ng-recaptcha": "^5.0.0",
        "ngx-logger": "^4.0.3",
        "npm": "^6.11.3",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~3.2.2"
    }
}
```

I want the hamburger to display navbar content on click event.
Please help me understand where I'm going wrong.
Any lead on this will really help..

Comment: Where are you adding those `script` elements? Angular strip down those elements from the templates. You should add those 2 URLs in the `angular.json` file, in the scripts array.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue, this works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-dew-jy62k

Comment: @David , the references are already present in the scripts array of angular.json. Please refer to the following  snipet.------"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true

Comment: @Cereal, i dont understand, why the hamburger is working fine in 'codesandbox' & not in my project ??

Comment: @user3794867 It is working because, he imported the dependencies directly in the HTML file. If you do the same on your end, it will probably also work however that may have some caveats as it is not the recommended way of including files in your angular app.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing  references:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Thanx for the immediate response @SemBauke.As you suggested, I've included the references in html & corrected their versions in package.json. But hamburger is not opening.can you please suggest if i'm missing anything else here

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4.3.1 depends on JQuery 3.3.1 for now, not 3.4 and also include popper.

As written in Bootstrap documentation

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It seems something changed... try using the input property.. Let's see

```
`
"styles": [{
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/global.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": [{
                "input": "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.min.js"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
              }
~
```

Comment: as you suggested, i corrected jquery & popper version, in my html as well as in package.json. But the issue still persists. Is there any other thing which i might be missing here..

Comment: It should be in the angular.json file not package.json

Comment: angular.json file contains scripts array which includes following -- "scripts": [
                            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                            "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
                            "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
                            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                        ],

Comment: Why are you putting a (./) before node_modules. It should be like this


`
 "styles": [

              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
`

Comment: are you sure thats the only change i've to make. despite of  which it still isn't working.

Comment: Please refer to the code snipet, eherin i've added angular.json & package.json

Comment: I tried with your piece of code..but its not helping

Comment: Maybe you should add the CDN in your index.html file. Stay Cool!

Comment: solved, it really worked after struggling for 4 hours.Thanx !!

Comment: By Adding CDN or ?

Comment: added references in index.html, uninstalled jquery & removed navbar-collapsed from div tag.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your navbar and it should be working fine. If you have any other questions just ask.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your site name</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Special Discounts </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products on Discount</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Please note that your references have to be included.

Comment: I really appreciate you editing the code to resolve the issue, but it still doesn't work. I did following steps from your suggestion 1) did npm install for popper & jquery suggested versions. 2) my scripts array in angular .json contains----      "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                            "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
                            "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
                            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ]    & the header.html includes refrences suggested by you inside <head>

Answer (score 1):

There are some known issues in bootstrap 4 with Angular, including the navbar component, so if you want to use Bootstrap with angular, I would recommend using the [`@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) or [`ngx-bootstrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap) packages since they are the most popular among other packages that might be out there.

If you want to use your own implementation, you could fix it by following this steps:

1. Add a click event listener to the button element in your template file.

```html
<button (click)="toggleNavbarCollapse()">Your icon here</button>
```

2. Add a property to the component to track the status of the navbar and a method that toggle its value.

```css
navbarCollapsed = true;

toggleNavbarCollapse() {
  this.navbarCollapsed = !this.navbarCollapsed;
}
```

3. Remove the `collapse` class from the `div` with the class `navbar-collapse`.
4. Add the `collapse` class dynamically based on the `navbarCollapsed` property.

```html
<div [ngClass]="{ collapse: navbarCollapsed }">...</div>
```

You can check more information on this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wab2ns).

Answer (score 0):

This link will provide you with sample implementation of Bootstrap 4 NavBar with Angular 7 https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/xH6VJo . Another valuable resource would be this [Bootstrap 4.1.1 Navbar not working with Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740093/bootstrap-4-1-1-navbar-not-working-with-angular-6) .. both can help you figuring out what are you missing in your implementation.

If you still not able to make it work , please send a git repository so I can run you project and debug.

Comment: i went through the given links. It still doesn't work.

Comment: can you share your repo?